# Use RainbowKit without Wagmi, and just with ethers.js

Tags: reactjs, solidity, smartcontracts, ethers.js

I like wagmi for what it is and the functionionality it offers, but wagmi has a couple limitations especially when it comes to calling function that return an output. So my take is this, A way to decouple rainbowkit a bit from wagmi, I understand rainbowkit is built on wagmi, but what I'm suggesting is to expose the wallet connector to ethers, a way to easily access useSigner and useProvider as just signer and provider for ethers to work with. The best of both world, a beautiful wallet connect modal without the limitatons of wagmi

I've tried using useSigner & useProvider hooks from wagmi, but they do not work with ethers.

Answer (score 1):

after 1 month of searching for solutions, I've finally realised where I got it wrong. Yes you can use rainbowkit without using wagmi to call contract functions, you just have to expose the signer, and use ethers with the signer/provider to interact with the smart contract functions

Where I got it wrong earlier, was defining the signer the wrong way using;

```
const Signer = async () => await useSigner();
```

and

```
  const signer = useSigner();
```

when it should have been [this](https://wagmi.sh/react/hooks/useSigner)

const { data: signer } = useSigner()

it works fine now, I don't need to use wagmi hooks to interact with smart contract functions, I can just use the signer from wagmi/rainbowkit with plain ethers and it works. Now I finally have the best of both worlds... Thank God